# find the number of function?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, functions

The number of functions f : {1, 2, . . . , 10} → {1, 2, . . . , 10} such that f(x)$ \neq $x  for all x is

(A) 10!

(B) $ {9^{10}} $

(C) $ {10^9} $

(D) $ {10^{10}} $   −  1.

My attemtp;   https://math.stackexchange.com/users/122131/ennar advice  first time i was using maths jax .i was try write B) 9 ^10 and  D) 10^10 - 1.. ..some thinking came in my mind that

if σ :{ 1,2,,,10} $ \rightarrow ${1,2,,,10} is one -one implies  σ $\in$ S10 . and every σ $\in$ S10 can be written as a cycle or as a product of disjoint cycles....now im  very confused  that how can i find the number of function  .....pliz help me and tell me the solution..

Comment: It doesn't specify that the function has to be one-to-one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $x$ you have $9$ choices, so $9^{10}$.

Comment: here f(x) $ /eq  $  x ,,,,,,how can i have 9 choice @Yves Doaust...can u elaborate ?

Comment: @lomberlego: come on. $1\to2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$.

Comment: ok,,,i got the point ,,,,thanks u so much @Yves Daoust